# Latex cannot be rendered in IntelliSense of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, intellisense

[image]

Python Codes:

```
import cv2
cv2.bitwise_or()
```

When I was writing this code, the function declaration showed up. But there is something wrong with latex. I don't know why them cannot be rendered.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Hi! please post no screenshot but some minimal code that we can compile to see where the problem is: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that - Further, I do believe it may be \f or something doing trouble instead of \texttt. Also post your error or warning!!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I have revised the description of the problem.